# I want to make separated file for telegram bot every commands in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

pytelegrambotapii am making a telegram bot and i want to make every command in separated files i tried to do with this code

```
from run_start import *
@bot.message_handler(commands=['cmds'])
async def semd_command(message):
    await bot.reply_to(message,"Commands\n\nComing Soon")
```

how to attach 2 files pytelegrambotapi

in 1st line import is main file whare bot running

When i put that code in main file its working but when i put separated its not working please give me solution

This is my first code

```
import cmds

bot = AsyncTeleBot('token')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['help', 'start'])
async def send_welcome(message):  
    await bot.reply_to(message,"__Heya__!! boiiiii How was your day???")
    await bot.reply_to(message,"Now Send /cmds to check my commands")
asyncio.run(bot.polling())
```

Answer (score 0):

**I hope these basic templates help:**

- [AsyncTeleBot](https://github.com/coder2020official/asynctelebot_template)
- [TeleBot](https://github.com/coder2020official/telebot_template)